# Generate child certificate from CA-issued HTTP cert

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, httpserver

So, I have a wildcard certificate which is signed by a respectable CA that all browsers recognize (Equifax). This certificate is valid for *.mydomain.com and works well.

Now, what I would like to do is use this cert to sign a certificate for a subdomain like something.mydomain.com -- I don't want to use my main (wildcard) certificate for this sublocation for security reasons.

Here is a diagram of the certificate chain I am looking to achieve :

Equifax CA ==1==> *.mydomain.com ==2==> something.mydomain.com

I am looking to do arrow #2, as well as configure lighttpd correctly with the resulting cert.

I have managed to generate a certificate using OpenSSL, and given lighty a ca-crt file with both the wildcard and CA certs. However this fails to validate in my browser (it does not seem to see the chain). 'openssl s_client' sees only 2 certs in the chain (from mydomain.com) but does not include the root CA cert...

Am I doing something wrong? (Is this even possible?) Any pointers much appreciated :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Only certificates that are specifically marked as CA certificates can sign other certificates (and then they can sign *any* other certificates, so those aren't handed out lightly).

It is a bit of a pity - the ability to have "domain-limited CA" certificates would be nice.